# Need a groovy Script for the Date Parsing add 3 business days

Tags: groovy, calendar

Need to add 3 days from the date which i'm getting, But i need to avoid the date come for the Days Sat and sun....

i'm using the below code..

```
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

//String dt = "2016-10-12";  // Start date
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(sdf.parse(dt));
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 3);  // number of days to add
op = sdf.format(c.getTime());  // dt is now the new date
```

given scenario  need to use....3 business days should be added

```
Monday +3 days
Tuesday +3 days
Wednesday +5 days
Thursday +5 days
Friday +5 days
Saturday +4 days
Sunday +3 days
```

In javaScript i'm using the code but i need this in groovyScript .. i'm new to this, i don't know how to do that.... i need help ...

```
var day = weekday[ invoiceDatee.getDay() ];
switch(day) {
    case "Sunday":
        invoiceDatee.setDate(invoiceDatee.getDate() + 3);
        break;
    case "Monday":
        invoiceDatee.setDate(invoiceDatee.getDate() + 3);
        break;
    case "Tuesday":
       invoiceDatee.setDate(invoiceDatee.getDate() + 3);
        break;
    case "Wednesday":
       invoiceDatee.setDate(invoiceDatee.getDate() + 5);
        break;
    case "Thursday":
       invoiceDatee.setDate(invoiceDatee.getDate() + 5);
        break;
    case "Friday":
       invoiceDatee.setDate(invoiceDatee.getDate() + 5);
        break;
    case "Saturday":
       invoiceDatee.setDate(invoiceDatee.getDate() + 4);
        break;
    default:
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
def map = [1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 5, 5: 5, 6: 5, 7: 4]
c.add(Calendar.DATE, map[c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)]);  // number of days to add
```

Comment: Thanks Adeel Ansari.... It's not working.
illegal colon after argument expression;                                                                                                                                                                                 
solution: a complex label expression before a colon must be parenthesized @ line 8, column 32.                                                                                                                                                      
Calendar.SATURDAY:4;

Comment: @Kumar, sorry I haven't compiled the code. Updated it, should work now.

Comment: @Kumar, you may not be able to upvote, but I believe, you can accept my answer, if it works for you.